# i need to take the jquery parameter out of the html, how can i convert this to a function?

Tags: jquery

this resides inside the body tag in an HTML file and provides parameters to the jquery accordion function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 

$("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex:    null});
});
</script>
```

I want to save this as an external JavaScript file and call the function to do the same thing.

I am a newbie, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace it with:
    <script src="script.js"></script>

and create a new file called script.js with the code that used to be in the script tags:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex:    null});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Erm, don't put `<script>` tags into the `<body>`. It's not a good practice.

Putting the JS code into an external file is much better for readability and functionality in general. Make a new file, let's say `script.js` and paste in your code:

**script.js**

```
$(function() { 
  $("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex:    null});
});
```

And in your HTML file, instead of putting the JS code in between the `<script>` tags, just add a `src` attribute to tell the browser that the JS code is located in `script.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: clarifying -- script tags in the body are okay if they are used with an src, but adding the javascript itself inline is not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeTabs(elementId) {
        jQuery("#" + elementId).tabs("#" + elementId + " div.pane", {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex:    null});
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's what the OP was asking, since that still leaves him with code in the html page, and not in an external JS file.

Comment: oops. you're right @snowBlind. I thought he wanted to make it into a function for reuse which was not the point.